# Не могу заполнить NaN значения Pandas

Tags: pandas

Я использую Pandas для предобработки данных.
Пропущенные значения хочу заполнить **модой** по каждому столбцу.
Но при выполнении кода все равно остается 21 пропущенное значение...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно при обучении модели выдает ошибку

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: вообще не понял, в чем проблема с оформлением? что значит "в виде текста"?

Comment: `sum(df.isnull().sum())` — это в виде текста. а у вас в вопросе тот же самый текст нарисован на картинке.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)